# I need help because I don't understand why my code is not performing filtering by date? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I perform the filtering, no value is returned to me

[my view index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vCl3.png)

I think the problem is in my ActionResult Index but I don't know what it is, because i think the references are correct.what I know in my index controller is converting the variable DataTime to String

My Model

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Registo { get; set; }
public Programa()
    {
        Data_Registo = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
    {
        if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
        {
            //this will default to current date if for whatever reason the date supplied by user did not parse successfully

            DateTime start = DateManager.GetDate(startdate) ?? DateTime.Now;

            DateTime end = DateManager.GetDate(enddate) ?? DateTime.Now;

            var rangeData = db.Programa.Where(x => x.Data_Registo >= start && x.Data_Registo <= end).ToList();

            return View(rangeData);
        }
        return View(db.Programa);
    }


    public class DateManager
    {

        static bool IsMonthAssigned { get; set; }



        public static DateTime? GetDate(string d)
        {
            char[] splitsoptions = { '/', '-', ' ' };
            foreach (var i in splitsoptions)
            {
                var y = 0;
                var m = 0;
                var day = 0;
                if (d.IndexOf(i) > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (var e in d.Split(i))
                        {


                            if (e.Length == 4)
                            {
                                y = Convert.ToInt32(e);

                                continue;
                            }
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(e) <= 12 && !IsMonthAssigned)
                            {
                                m = Convert.ToInt32(e);
                                IsMonthAssigned = true;
                                continue;
                            }
                            day = Convert.ToInt32(e);


                        }

                        return new DateTime(y, m, day);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            return null;


        }


        public static DateTime? GetDate(string d, bool custom)
        {
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            string[] dateFormats =
            {
            "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/dd/MM", "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "yyyy-dd-MM", "dd MM yyyy", "MM dd yyyy", "yyyy MM dd", "yyyy dd MM", "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy",
            "yyyy.MM.dd", "yyyy.dd.MM","yyyyMMdd","yyyyddMM","MMddyyyy","ddMMyyyy"
        };//add your own to the array if any

            culture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(dateFormats, 'Y');

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(d, dateFormats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var date))
                return date;

            return null;


        }
    }
```

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Programas", FormMethod.Get))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Search criteria</legend>
    @Html.Label("StartDate", "Start Date:")
    <input class="startdate" id="startdate" name="startdate" type="date" value="">
    @Html.Label("enddate", "End Date:")
    <input class="startdate" id="enddate" name="enddate" type="date" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</fieldset>
}
```

**(UPDATE)**
I tried to create a direct entry but data is not loaded from the database

```
        public ActionResult Index(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {

            var programas = db.Programa.Where(x => x.Data_Registo >= start && x.Data_Registo <= end).ToList();

        return View(programas.ToList());


    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: There's some basic debugging information it would be good for you to add in such a whether the values of `start` and `end` are being correctly set in your controller action. If they are not then what are the strings you are passing in to your parser? Also why do you seem to have written your own parser? Also can oyu not just specify a specific date format that you expect to be passed? This would make your life much easier...

Comment: Did you try to change your action signature to public ActionResult Index(DateTime? startdate , DateTime? enddate)  and not to use your custom converters?

Comment: i need to convert my DataTime variable to string for my data entry right?
or is it possible to enter data in DataTime with my database? Im a little confused.  Im new this code was made with parts of code that are available here on the forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to filter between dates, nothing like being as simple as possible.
I leave code below so you need to filter by dates.

```
public ActionResult Index(string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
    {
        if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
        {

            DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);

            DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);

            var rangeData = db.YourTable.Where(x => x.YourColumn >= start && x.YourColumn<= end).ToList();

            return View(rangeData);
        }
        return View(db.YourTable.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database SHOULD allow a datetime column that already stores data in a proper date and time format.  You should not have to parse it all over in different formats.  Then, when you query it and want those particular parts, there are datetime functions to extract things like year, month, day, hour, minute, second from it.  And printing/displaying the output would be part of the formatting AFTER you have the data.  You also do not indicate which database you are working with.  Do a search on that database plus datetime functions and you'll see a lot of stuff... MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.